# C# to Access connection in Visual Form OleDb No data exists for the row/column OR invalid output

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I am trying to get a Text value from a single cell in an Access form, but this code gives me `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader` as an output instead. When I change Sell to *, and `Convert.ToString(cusReader)` to `Convert.ToString(cusReader.getValue(1))`, I get the error in the title.
How do I fix this?
Thanks, Jack.

```
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Sell FROM Product WHERE ID = " + Count, conn);
            OleDbDataReader cusReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (Count != 0)
            {
                labelInsertedExtra.Visible = true;
                labelInserted.Visible = true;
                labelInsertedExtra.Text = Convert.ToString(cusReader);
            }
            else
            {
                labelInsertedExtra.Visible = false;
                labelInserted.Visible = false;
            }
            cusReader.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indice start to 0

```
   Convert.ToString(cusReader.getValue(0))
```

you should test dbnullvalue too

```
      while (cusReader.Read())
      {

        if (Count != 0 && cusReader["Sell"] != DBNull.Value)
        {
            labelInsertedExtra.Visible = true;
            labelInserted.Visible = true;
            labelInsertedExtra.Text = cusReader["Sell"].ToString(); 
        }
        else
        {
            labelInsertedExtra.Visible = false;
            labelInserted.Visible = false;
        }

        break;
      }
```

Comment: Still getting 'No date exists for the row/column'

And there is definitely a value in this position

Comment: Alright, I tried the `cusReader["sell"].ToString()` and still, no data exists... if you would like to know, the Access table has 9 entries, with ID, productName, Cost and Sell. All but ID are Short text.
Thanks for helping thus far

Comment: attention to the case "sell" is different to "Sell", and you must test DBNull.Value like above

Comment: Sorry, that's just from me retyping the code lazily, i have Sell in the actual program. I am now getting `No data exists for the row/column` on the if statement...

Comment: sorry i have forget the read (long time i have not used datareader), i have modify my code now correctly

Comment: That has fixed it! I think the issue from the very start was the `while (cusReader.Read())` being missing. Thank you for your help, Esperento